# Return individual cell values from a wildcard search against a range into individual cells using Excel

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup, excel-2016, excel-match

so I've been trying to work out this problem in Excel (Office 2016, Mac El Capitan, latest updates installed) but have failed so far.

In essence, I would like to search a range of cells (in this case A2:A9) for a partial keyword (A2). Hence all cells that match this criterium should then appear in the result range (E2:E9). I already struggle with this, as I'm only able to return a single result (e.g. one row entry in E2). I have attempted this with INDEX and MATCH but have failed so far.

After this, I would then look-up the corresponding quantity in range B2:B9 using vlookup, this works for now.

The final, desired outcome is attached as an image.

Thanks a lot for your help.

[image: desired results]

Comment: I am going out on a limb here, but I am guess the entry of "dog" in E4 should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Apply the formula below to E2 and copy down as far as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A:A)/ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,A:A)),ROW(A1))),"no more entries")
```

in F2 use the following formula and copy down as required as well

```
=SUMIF(A:A,E2,B:B)
```

A few caveats.

1. Since the first formula is performing array like calculations inside the aggregate function, full column references should be avoided.  Change `A:A` to `$A$2:$A$9`or whatever your range is.
2. Column A is assumed to be full of unique names
3. The search is not case sensitive.  If you need it to be change `SEARCH` to `FIND`
4. If you do not want to see "no more entries" change it to ""

Answer (score 0):

In `Cell E2` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($C$2,$A$2:$A$9)),ROW($A$2:$A$9)-1),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required.

Then to get corresponding quantity enter following formula in `Cell F2`

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$9,MATCH(E2,$A$2:$A$9,0))
```

Drag/Copy down as required. See image for reference.

[image]

Note: `SEARCH` function is case-insensitive. If you are looking for a case sensitive match, use `FIND` function.